# Can a switch parameter get value automatically?

Tags: php

In my company's website, there's some code which I don't understand. It works fine. See:

```
extract($_REQUEST);

switch(@$task){

        //Only for tracker app/ Later move to seperate api///
    case "get_all_trackers":
        $trackerObj = new trackerClass('trackerClass');
        echo $service = $trackerObj->getAllTrackers($_POST);
        break;
    default:
        //dsfsdfdsf
}
```

Now, you can see $task is not defined ("according to me"). But it somehow takes the **string** 'get_all_trackers' when requested. I came to know about this when I used PostMan and gave a parameter `task=get_all_trackers` and it worked. I even changed the name of $task to $somethingelse, and it still worked. How's it taking the value?

Comment: [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract) does the magic, setting the REQUEST key as the variable. Hence why if you change the name of `task` in Postman and the script it still works. `$task` is essentially `$_REQUEST['task']`.

Comment: Okay, but how does changing the name of varialbe doesn't affect it? The changed variable name is not same as the post key?

Comment: What are you changing?

Comment: If you know we can use params in PostMan. I first changed the `switch($changedName)` variable name and used the same name `changedName` as key in the PostMan and still found the same response. Why is it so? `extract()` returns the variable name same as the key in the array?

Comment: You changed the name on both.... which means it would work because `extract()` set it as that new variable name....and then you check against that new variable name...

Comment: DId you understand?

Comment: Okay, you want to say both the key is also changed when I used different params in PostMan?

Comment: Read the documentation on [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract) to understand how it works.

Comment: I understood, but could you please reply my last comment?

Answer (score 0):

**No**. The one that's doing this is the [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function. Based on your code, it assigns variables with names and values according to the `$_REQUEST` array key and value pairs.

Example:

Let's say the current URL is `http://yourwebsite.com/yourpage.php?foo=bar`.
Then `$_REQUEST['foo']` would have a value of `"bar"`. And if you use `extract($_REQUEST)`, you would have a variable `$foo`, which has a value of `"bar"`.

Comment: When I did `var_dump($_REQUEST)` I saw an array with `task=get_all_records` value. So here we have `task` key but why didn't it affect the result even when I changed the parameter variable of switch?

Comment: @VikasKumar What do you mean you changed the parameter variable of switch?

Comment: If you know we can use params in PostMan. I first changed the `switch($changedName)` variable name and used the same name changedName as key in the PostMan and still found the same response. Why is it so? `extract()` returns the variable name same as the key in the array?

Comment: Please read documentation of extract. http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: I agree with @Ima, continue with this by reading the `extract()` documentation. It will make it clearer.